# Laravel Eloquent group by relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm struggling to understand how to use Eloquent/Query Builder with relationships.

I have the following:

```
$plantLots = PlantLot::with('controlNumber')
   ->whereHas('controlNumber', function ($q) use ($fromDate, $toDate) {
        $q->where('created_at', '>=', $fromDate);
        if($toDate != '') {
           $q->where('created_at', '=<', $toDate);
        }
        $q->groupBy('creator_id');
   })->get();
```

I want to group by `creator_id`, but I still just get a single collection of data.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
$plantLots = PlantLot::with(['controlNumber' => function($q){
       $q->groupBy('creator_id');
   }])
   ->whereHas('controlNumber', function ($q) use ($fromDate, $toDate) {
     $q->where('created_at', '>=', $fromDate)
       ->when($toDate != '',function($q){
         $q->where('created_at', '=<', $toDate);
      });
  })->get();
```

Hope it helps.